# In R, find elements of a vector in a list using vectorization

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a vector v1

```
v1 = c(1, 200, 4000)
```

I would like to find the indices of the elements of v1 in a list L1 vectorially, i.e. without a loop, where

```
> L1
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 100 200 300 400

[[3]]
[1] 1000 2000 3000 4000
```

The output should be c(1, 2, 4).

Is there a way to do this without using a loop or apply (which is computationally the same as using a loop?) I have to do this for very long vectors.

Comment: Is there any overlap between the elements of `L1`? To be clear, is it possible that a value belongs to both `L1[[1]]` and `L1[[2]]`? Another question: you want to check the position of the first element of `v1` inside the first element of `L1`, the second with the second and so on?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. L1 is random with respect to v1.

Comment: Ok thanks. What about the second question of my comment above?

Comment: sorry didnt see it... yes each element of v1 should be checked against each element of L

Comment: If so, the proposed answers won't give you the desired output in the general case.

Comment: Now the @akrun edit addresses fully your request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can do this, seems to be the fastest by far.

```
v1 <- c(1, 200, 4000)
L1 <- list(1:4, 1:4*100, 1:4*1000)

sequence(lengths(L1))[match(v1, unlist(L1))]
# [1] 1 2 4
sequence(lengths(L1))[which(unlist(L1) %in% v1)]
# [1] 1 2 4
```

---

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(tidyverse)

microbenchmark(
  akrun_sapply = {sapply(L1, function(x) which(x %in% v1))},
  akrun_Vectorize = {Vectorize(function(x) which(x %in% v1))(L1)},
  akrun_mapply = {mapply(function(x, y) which(x %in% y), L1, v1)},
  akrun_mapply_match = {mapply(match, v1, L1)},
  akrun_map2 = {purrr::map2_int(L1, v1, ~ .x %in% .y %>% which)},
  CPak = {setNames(rep(1:length(L1), times=lengths(L1)), unlist(L1))[as.character(v1)]},
  zacdav = {sequence(lengths(L1))[match(v1, unlist(L1))]},
  zacdav_which = {sequence(lengths(L1))[which(unlist(L1) %in% v1)]},
  times = 10000
)

Unit: microseconds
               expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq        max neval
       akrun_sapply  18.187  22.7555  27.17026  24.6140  27.8845   2428.194 10000
    akrun_Vectorize  60.119  76.1510  88.82623  83.4445  89.9680   2717.420 10000
       akrun_mapply  19.006  24.2100  29.78381  26.2120  29.9255   2911.252 10000
 akrun_mapply_match  14.136  18.4380  35.45528  20.0275  23.6560 127960.324 10000
         akrun_map2 217.209 264.7350 303.64609 277.5545 298.0455   9204.243 10000
               CPak  15.741  19.7525  27.31918  24.7150  29.0340    235.245 10000
             zacdav   6.649   9.3210  11.30229  10.4240  11.5540   2399.686 10000
       zacdav_which   7.364  10.2395  12.22632  11.2985  12.4515   2492.789 10000
```

Answer (score 8):

We can do

```
sapply(L1, function(x) which(x %in% v1))
#[1] 1 2 4
```

Or with `Vectorize`

```
Vectorize(function(x) which(x %in% v1))(L1)
#[1] 1 2 4
```

---

If each element is checked against corresponding element of another

```
mapply(function(x, y) which(x %in% y), L1, v1)
#[1] 1 2 4
```

As @nicola mentioned `match` could also be used to get the first index.  If there are duplicate elements, then `which` would be useful

```
mapply(match, v1, L1)
#[1] 1 2 4
```

Or using the `purrr::map2`

```
purrr::map2_int(L1, v1, ~ .x %in% .y %>%
                                    which)
#[1] 1 2 4
```

Comment: apply is the same as using a loop, in terms of computational efficiency

Comment: `sapply` is much much faster than `Vectorize` when you benchmark the example in the OP.

Comment: @zacdav Yes, it would be because `Vectorize` is still a loop.  But, the OPs example is a small one to get any meaningful insights

Comment: Actually `sapply` is a loop, so don't think this qualifies in being vectorized (tbf it depends on what one means by "vectorised").

Comment: @zacdav True -- and it isn't just the overhead of the call to `Vectorize`. `sapply` is still faster even when you first use `f <- Vectorize(function(x) which(x %in% v1))` and then microbenchmark the `sapply` approach against `f(L1)`

Comment: Lol, same time. Use `match` (more efficient): `mapply(match, v1, L1)`.

Comment: @akrun It's not an option, it's the option :) (using `which` you have a lot of useless comparisons).

Comment: if using match, may as well use `fastmatch::fmatch`

Comment: @nicola But, if there are duplicate elements, it will only give the index of first match, right

Comment: @akrun Right, but I guess that's intended, otherwise the output should (or might) be a list if we allow multiple matches.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this

```
v1 = c(1, 200, 4000)
L1 <- list(1:4, 1:4*100, 1:4*1000)

setNames(rep(1:length(L1), times=lengths(L1)), unlist(L1))[as.character(v1)]
# 1  200 4000 
# 1    2    3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use

```
unlist(lapply(L1, function(x) which(x %in% v1)))

#[1] 1 2 4
```

Or use

```
unlist(Map(function(x, y) which(x %in% y), L1, v1 ))
#[1] 1 2 4
```